# Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev Inequality w.r.t. general probability measure

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The [Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg%E2%80%93Sobolev_inequality) states that the $L^{p*}$ norm of a function with compact support is bounded by the $L^p$ norm of its derivative. Typically $L^p$ is in the sense of the Lebesgue integral on $\mathbb{\mathbb{R}^d}$. Can we get similar results if we consider a general probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in which the integration is with respect to $\mu$ instead of the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Look up "weighted Sobolev spaces".  Typically you'll need $\mu$ to be of the form $d\mu = \phi \,dm$ with $\phi$ sufficiently smooth, otherwise you can't say very much.  (For instance, consider what happens if $\mu$ is a point mass.)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you!